# Java: Export and Import a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Just wondering, is there anyway in JAVA to export a hashmap?

I know you define one through:

HashMap hmap = new HashMap();

And i have found examples of how you can grab or insert information to the hashmap, but i don't have any idea how to save the "hashmap", so that the data added during the program running once, could be accessed by the program added another time.

Basically, upon the program running, the user would add their name followed by an amount in the format UserName|Amount. 
And then you could close the program.
Next time you open the program you should be able to open the hashmap and get the amount tied to the User by using their UserName as a key.

This is the only way I've thought of doing it so far, but if there is a better way of doing it then please by all means, let me know :)

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, this is done by saving that information to a file or database on entry, then reading from the file or database each time the program opens.

Comment: Yes, i gathered it would be like this. Whats the best way of doing this do you think? Text file?

Comment: It really depends on your use case, but in almost all cases, it's going to be easier with some sort of structured data, like XML, JSON, or CSV. Look up some libraries for each of these formats and pick the one that looks the easiest. If your're only working in Java, @Midnightas looks like he has a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

How you save your data is entirely your choice.
I would preferably use the `java.util.Properties` class for this.
Whenever you want to "save" your `HashMap`, for-loop on it's contents and then call the `setProperty` method on your `Properties` field:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(inputStream); // Only call this if your properties file is not empty
for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry : yourHashMap.entrySet()) {
    props.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() + "");
}
props.store(outputStream, "Some comment here.");
```

I added `+ ""` to make sure that a `String` is passed.
The `"Some comment here."` is apparently necessary, although you can make it empty.

Comment: Right, thanks. Does this create a file somewhere? Also, what would input/output stream be?

Comment: The `outputStream` on `props.store` can be a `FileOutputStream` if you want to store it to a file.

Comment: Path outputStream = "/path/to/wherever"?
Putting this before the block would export the file to the given location?

Comment: `outputStream` must be a subclass of `java.io.OutputStream`. If you want to store it to a file, use `FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/wherever"));`

Comment: And what file type would be best for this? txt/json/yaml?

Comment: Properities files would be a good simple solution if your data is just key/value pairs and both keys and values are String. For more complex data structure, like having fields, you would probably want to use YAML/TOML or JSON, or as I suggested on my answer, MapDB to use it as a disk persisted HashMap

Comment: `HashMap` is always key-value, though.

Comment: Yes, but both the key and the value can be any Java class. You can still use String as key and value, but you can use a custom complex data type with the fields (and nested types) that you need, so it's much more powerful and versatile. Properties are a limited case of a HashMap were you only use String as key and value. Also, Properties are backed by HashSet

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap is a data structure that allows to store data in key/value pairs. A hash function is used to distribute the keys evenly and optimize retrieval.

The key can be anything, but a String is a common choice, and the value can be any Java class.

You don't really "close" a HashMap and "open" it again once the program is run again, since it topically exists only in memory so when you stop the JVM (the application), the data is gone.

To avoid losing the data which resides in memory you have to persist it. There are many ways of doing it:

- You can persist it to a database, SQL or NoSQL.
- You can persist it to disk in a file, with a standard format like CSV, XML, JSON, YAML, TOML, or a custom binary format. You can even directly serialize Java classes to disk.
- You can send the data over the network for another service to process or store, tipically serialized as JSON or XML.

From your question it seems you're trying to write a desktop application. You could store the data just as CSV or XML, or use a lightweight SQL database like SQLite, but in your case I think a good approach would be to use MapDB. You use it basically as a HashMap and you can save it to disk, and later you can read it from disk again, so it would be more or less what you were expecting to be able to do with HashMaps.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). This means that you could write the HashMap to an [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) which is backed by a [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) to write the HashMap to a file, and later you could read from the file using an [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) that's backed by a [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html). That's one way to do it, and one that is certainly very natural to the Java programming language.

Whether or not it's a good idea depends on your use-case, as others have pointed out already.

Please note that the entities of your HashMap must also be Serializable for this to work!